# Why I can't I add an API using swagger?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

Im a beginner at swagger. What im trying to do is creating an API and the problem is when test it on Postman, the Postman can't find the API.

This is my router:

```
router
  /**
   * @swagger
   * /orders/{id}/status:
   *  put:
   *    summary: accept the order
   *    tags: [Order]
   *    description: this action can accessd by driver  or admin
   *    responses:
   *      200:
   *        description: The order was updated
   *
   *      404:
   *        description: you are not authorized to access this route
   *      500:
   *        description: Some error happened
   */
  .route("/:id/status")
  .put(protect, authorize("user", "admin"), requestOrder);
```

This is my controller:

```
//@route put/api/v1/orders/:id
//@access private for admin & user who create  the order
exports.requestOrder = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const updatedOrder = await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { status: req.body.status },
    {
      new: true,
    }
  );
  if (!updatedOrder) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`error ${req.params.id}`, 404)
    );
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    msg: ` order with id ${req.params.id} is updated`,
    data: updatedOrder,
  });
});
```

I'm wondering if it is any mistake in the swagger code since i'm a  beginner, and not sure if I can notice any mistake in it.
In the postman I get error 404 (Cannot PUT)
Also im using MongoDb as a database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a Swagger config file and added your servers?

Example:

```
//./configs/openapi.js
module.exports = {
  openapi: '3.0.0',
  info: {
    title: 'Your API Titel',
    description: '',
    termsOfService: '',
    contact: {
      name: 'Your contact Details',
      url: 'https://example.com',
    },
    license: {},
  },
  servers: [
    {
      url: 'http://localhost:2000/api',
      description: 'Local development server',
    }
  ]
};
```

And then you need to import the config file in app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
swaggerDefinition = require('./config/openapi.js')

const options = {
    swaggerDefinition,
    // Paths to files containing OpenAPI definitions
    apis: ['src/routes/*js']
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

api.listen(config.api.port, () => {
  console.log('Server running at port 2000')
})
```

Comment: Yes I've done that , there are other API that are working and I'm trying to add another one and it's not working